# In Watership Down what was Lord Frith's gift to Rabscuttle?

Tags: childrens-novel, watership-down

When El-ahrairah and Rabscuttle reach their home warren after their journey home from the abode of the Black Rabbit of Inle, they have an encounter with Lord Frith, who has some gifts for them (end of chapter 31):

> I have brought a few trifles for you [El-ahrairah]. A pair of ears, a tail, and some whiskers...Ah, there is Rabscuttle coming back. Good, I have something for him, too.

But before we hear what Rabscuttle's gift was Hazel and the other rabbits listening to the story are interrupted by the approach of a fox.

Rabscuttle's gift seems important, but if there were any insights to be gleaned about its nature in either *Watership Down* or *Tales From Watership Down*, I missed them. Did I miss something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Watership Down is not a work of Science Fiction of Fantasy, and as such is off-topic.

Comment: related meta discussion: [Are anthropomorphic animals by themselves enough to deem a work fantasy?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/5117/5184)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watership_Down its tagged as fantasy. this guy says its fantasy as well http://www.tor.com/2010/10/19/rabbit-realism-and-folklore-richard-adamss-watership-down/

Comment: @Himarm That doesn't change this sites policy on anthropomorphic animals. Additionally, in the first sentence it is described as a classic adventure novel, not a fantasy novel - that information only appears in the sidebar.

Comment: @DrRDizzle have you read the book, its fantasy... its a classic hero saves the day story typical of what you would see in a fantasy novel with people - one of the rabbits sees visions, which would give 100% fantasy tag anyway. despite the talking rabbits. it also won fiction awards, no big deal, its not fiction tho right?

Comment: @Himarm Watership Down was one of the first books me and my father read together. Questions about off-topic works are only on-topic if they are specifically about a fantastical/science-fictional element of the story, which this isn't.

Comment: @DrRDizzle the book isnt off topic, and even if the book is off topic, look at the question hes asking about the mythical god character aka a fantastical element of the story.

Comment: @Himarm A story being told by rabbits, not the sudden appearance of fantastical creatures. I maintain that the book is off-topic.

Comment: i've said it before, and i'll say it again - *wikipedia is not a reliable measure of what is, or isn't SF/F - much less what is on topic on our site*.

Comment: @phantom42 one of the rabbits goes into trances and sees the future, which is a major plot point in the book, seeing the future is a fantasy element, and again as its central to the story, aka they act on these visions, this book is fantasy.

we have 2 magic rabbits, end of story, gg...

Comment: That's fine - judge it on the work itself, not on what wikipedia says or how any other site categorizes it.

Comment: @phantom42 i mentioned that, and then proceeded to link multiple reviews on the book, all of which tagged it as fantasy (based on the that point) as support.

Comment: "or how any other site categorizes it." i don't care what random reviewer deems is sf/f. if *we* don't, it's off-topic.

Comment: My personal feeling is that, in disputed cases our default position should be "Inclusion". Quid Non?

Comment: Please feel free to jump into chat where discussion on this is taking place.

Comment: The author states that there is no fantastical content that would bring it on-topic here. It is merely a novel about talking rabbits; http://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/jan/04/richard-adams-watership-down-interview

Comment: @Richard From the article you link to "I’m a fantasist."—Richard Adams. Moreover, the portions of *Watership Down* featuring El-ahrairah, Rabscuttle, the Black Rabbit of Inle, and Lord Frith—precisely the subjects of the question—are *prima facie* fantasy.

Comment: @Lexible - While I disagree, if the community votes to reopen, I shan't oppose it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've checked in *Watership Down* and *Tales From Watership Down,* as well as a few fan sites and as far as I can tell the story of *El-ahrairah and the Black Rabbit of Inlé* is left unfinished (the storyteller, Dandelion, is interrupted by the appearance of a fox). We never get to know what Lord Frith gave to Rabscuttle.

So the only answer is that no, you didn't miss anything.